# What is the ".data..init_task" section in the Linux Kernel code?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel

I am exploring the Linux Kernel code and came across this line of code:

```
#define __init_task_data __attribute__((__section__(".data..init_task"))).
```

I know that something like:

```
int x __attribute__((__section__("section"))) = 10;
```

is an attribute of gcc which would put the symbol of x into the section "section" of the compiled process image. However when I try to specify ".data..init_task" as the section, my variable gets put into the .data section. Here is my code:

```
int apple __attribute__((__section__(".data..init_task"))) = 10;
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc test.c
```

Disassembled with:

```
objdump -D a.out
```

My variable "apple" appears under the .data section, there is no section ".data..init_task" which is what has stumped me.

Comment: Attribute `__section__` specifies **input section** from the sence of the linker. **Outpus section**, which is stored into the ELF file, is determined by the linker script as a mapping from the input  section. It seems, that default linker script (non-kernel one) maps all `.data.*` *input sections* into `.data` *output section*. But the Linux kernel's linker script maps `.data..init_task` section with the same name.

Comment: yes you are right, for example to reproduce the issue I was facing above a linker script with something similar to: `.data { (.data)*; }` would put .data..init_task into the .data section.